# Continuity of an operator in $C^0[0,1]$ with different norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $C^0[0,1]$ be the space of real valued continuos functions with the norm $\|f\| = \int \limits_{0}^1 x^2 |f(x)| dx$ and let $T \colon C^0[0,1] \to C^0[0,1]$ such that $f(x) \mapsto f(1-x)$. Is $T$ continuos?

Comment: My initial guess is: T is not bounded. So i tried the sequence $f_n(0) = 3n^2$ and a linear function to 0 such that $f_n(1/n)=0$. Then $\|f\|=1$ But I cant prove that $\| T(f)\| $ is unbounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $f \in C([0,1])$ you have $Tf(x) = f(1-x)$ so that $$\|f\| = \int_0^1 x^2 f(x) \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad 
 \|Tf\| = \int_0^1 x^2 |f(1-x)|\, dx.$$
If $f$ is concentrated near $0$, the first norm will be small and the second norm will be large.

One way to look for counterexamples is to temporarily disregard continuity: for instance you could take $f_n(x) = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$. Then $$\|f_n\| = \frac{1}{3n^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \|Tf_n\| = \frac{n}{3} \left[ 1 - \left( 1 - \frac 1n \right)^3 \right].$$ Thus $\|f_n\| \to 0$ but $\|Tf_n\| \to \dfrac 13$, so $T$ is not continuous.

Comment: How can we transform this sequence to a sequence in $C^0$? Isnt it necessary?

Comment: Can you think of a continuous function that is really, really, close to $f_n$?

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 12 n^4 ({1 \over n} -x), & x< {1 \over n} \\
0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.
 Then $\|f_n\| = 1$, however $\|Tf_n\| = {n^2 \over 2} - {n \over 3} + { 1\over 12}$.